# Lua - SQLite3 isn't inserting rows into its database

Tags: database, sqlite, calendar, lua, coronasdk

I'm trying to build an expense app for Android phones, and I need a way to display the expenses. The plan (for my current step) is to allow the user to view their expenses. I want to show a calendar-like screen, and if there is at least one expense for a day, then use a different color for the button.

My problem is in inserting information to the `sqlite3` table. Here is my code:

```lua
require "sqlite3"

--create path
local path = system.pathForFile("expenses.sqlite", system.DocumentsDirectory )
file = io.open( path, "r" )
if( file == nil )then           
    -- Doesn't Already Exist, So Copy it In From Resource Directory                          
    pathSource = system.pathForFile( "expenses.sqlite", system.ResourceDirectory )  
    fileSource = io.open( pathSource, "r" ) 
    contentsSource = fileSource:read( "*a" )                                  
    --Write Destination File in Documents Directory                                  
    pathDest = system.pathForFile( "expenses.sqlite", system.DocumentsDirectory )                 
    fileDest = io.open( pathDest, "w" )                 
    fileDest:write( contentsSource )                 
     -- Done                      
    io.close( fileSource )        
    io.close( fileDest )         
end
db = sqlite3.open( path )

--setup the table if it doesn't exist
local tableSetup = [[CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS expenses (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, amount, description, year, month, day);]]
db:exec(tableSetup)
local tableFill = [[INSERT INTO expenses VALUES (NULL,']] .. 15 .. [[',']] .. "Groceries" .. [[',']] .. 2013 .. [[',']] .. 4 .. [[',']] .. 8 ..[[');]]
db:exec(tableFill)

for row in db:nrows("SELECT * FROM expenses") do
        print("hi")
        if row.year == dateTable[i].year and row.month == dateTable[i].month and row.day == dateTable[i].day then
            flag = dateTabel[i].day
        end
end
```

I have looked everywhere to see if I've used the wrong sqlite3 commands wrong since I'm not very familiar to it, but I tried everything I found and nothing worked. The `print("hi")`
 line doesn't execute, so that tells me that there are no rows in the table.

Also, if I say `db:nrows("SELECT year, month, day FROM expenses")`, sqlite3 gives me an error saying there is no year column. My overall guess is that I'm not inserting the information into the table properly, but I've tried everything I can think of. Can anyone help?

Comment: SO needs a better Lua interpreter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that there was an issue with the current version of sqlite3 and the one I have on my computer. Anyway, I changed a couple of lines and it works flawlessly. I changed the select statement and the for loop.

```
        --sqlite statement
        local check = "SELECT DISTINCT year, month, day FROM expenses WHERE year = '"..dateTable[i].year.."' AND month = '"..dateTable[i].month.."' AND day = '"..dateTable[i].day.."'"

        --check if there is at least one expense for a given day
        --if there isn't one, the for loop won't execute
        for row in db:nrows(check) do
            flag = row.day
        end
```

Then I go on to create a button with a different color if the day number is equal to the flag variable.

This is all inside a another for loop which creates each `dateTable[i]`.